# Getting null when print attribute of class after assign value from json

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, dio

I have class CityModel when trying to assign value to it and print any value got null value now real value.

here CityModel class file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CityModel {
      String cityId;
      String nameAr;
      CityModel({@required cityId, @required nameAr});
}
```

here Provider function where I try to assign values to class city attributes

```
Response response = await httpService.getRequest(url);
  var parsedCities = response.data['data']['cities'] as List;

  if (response.statusCode == 200 && response.data['status_code'] == 201) {
    parsedCities.forEach((cityObject) {
      final String name = cityObject['name_ar'];

      final CityModel city =
          CityModel(cityId: cityObject['city_id'], nameAr: cityObject['name_ar']);
      cities.add(city);
      print(city.nameAr);
    });
```

parsedCitites contain list of cities objects
if i print cityObject['name_ar] i got the correct value
but my problem is when itry to print city.name_ar after value assgined to i got null
i don't know why.

Comment: share your error log

Comment: @MoaidALRazhy there is no error just print null not the correct value

Answer (score 0):

Try this? There is some type casting happening when you declare 'final String name = ....':

```
Response response = await httpService.getRequest(url);
  var parsedCities = response.data['data']['cities'] as List;

  if (response.statusCode == 200 && response.data['status_code'] == 201) {
    parsedCities.forEach((cityObject) {
      final String name = cityObject['name_ar'];
      final String city = cityObject['city_id'];
      print(name);
      print(city);
      final CityModel city =
          CityModel(cityId: city, nameAr: name);
      cities.add(city);
      print(city.nameAr);
      print(city.cityId);
    });
```

Comment: i tried your code and nothing printed i change cityId to Integer now print city_id and name
but still city.nameAr and city.cityId print null

Comment: thanks i found the error.
i forget to add this keyword in model class